# rake import leads to no model ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a rails app using psql and am importing a csv file into rails through a bundle exec rake import function.  When I do so, however, I noticed that my model doesn't have any ids associated with them.  My model is called Five and when I go into the rails console to check for ids after the import, I get id = nil (see code below).  The rake import is loading the dataset(I checked via Five.count in the console).  Any idea why the model isn't assigning ids?  I need the ids to call them in other commands in the app.

**Console ID Check**

```
2.2.1 :011 > Five.count
   (1.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "fives"
 => 100 
2.2.1 :012 > Five.first.valid?
  Five Load (4.3ms)  SELECT  "fives".* FROM "fives" LIMIT 1
 => true
2.2.1 :003 > Five.first.id
  Five Load (5.6ms)  SELECT  "fives".* FROM "fives" LIMIT 1
 => nil
```

**Rake Import Code, located in lib/tasks/import.rake**

```
desc "Imports a CSV file into an ActiveRecord table"
task :import, [:filename] => :environment do    
    CSV.foreach('/Users/UserName/desktop/test55.csv', :headers => true) do |row|
      Five.create! row.to_hash
    end
end
```

**Five Controller**

```
class FivesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @fives = Five.paginate(:per_page => 12, :page => params[:page])

  end

   def show
     @user = current_user 
     @five = Five.find(params[:id])
  end


  def import
     Five.import(params[:file])
     redirect_to fives_path, notice: "Fives imported."
  end

    def create
    @five = Five.new(five_params)

    respond_to do |format|      
      if @five.save
        format.html { redirect_to @five, notice: 'Five was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @five }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @five.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # GET /users/new
  def new
    @five = Five.new
  end

    def five_params
      params.require(:five).permit(:SPONSOR_DFE_NAME)
    end

end
```

**DB Schmea**

```
  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "fives", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text    "row.names"
    t.boolean "SPONS_DFE_EIN"
    t.text    "Filing_Date"
    t.text    "Filing_Type"
    t.text    "Filing_Method"
    t.text    "Filing_Name"
    t.text    "Plan_Name"
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: `Five.create! row.to_hash`, what does row.to_hash look like? the reason they have ids is because they're not persisting...

Comment: Hi neo, thanks for your response. I'm unsure what you mean by what does row.to_hash look like.  The only reason that code is there, is cause it was part of a tutorial I watched, showing how to import using the rake import function.  I just tried removing it, and running the rake import function, but still no ids.  Any ideas on what code I might need to add to have the model id persist?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Maybe smth with the DB schema for Five. Could you show it? Is id the primary_key?

Comment: Hi Aurel, thanks for your response. I just posted some schema code.  Note, you'll see ID says false, I tried changing it to true, but still no ids.  Also, there are a lot of attributes, but I cut them short, so I didn't take up too much space on here.

Comment: No need to specify id at all, try just this:

create_table "fives", force: :cascade do |t|

Comment: Aurel, your solution worked!  THANK YOU!  Might I ask why we needed to remove id: false, code?  What is that in there for?  I always want to learn, that's why I'm asking.  Also, if you add the code, I will check as answered.